# JQuery accordion keeps moving to top of the page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a simple JQuery accordion at the top of my page in html, the problem is that everytime i click a box to slide down the page moves to the very top again. I dont get why this would even happen and have spent countless hours determining if its a css issue or JQuery.

Im a JQuery noob so im not sure if there is a specific control to fix this or not.

I will provide my code (there is also a content slider on the page):

**CSS**

```
.clear
{
 clear:both;
}


body
{
    background: #0B0909;
    min-height: 200px; 
}

.wrap
{
     width:940px;
     padding:10px;
     margin:50px auto;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Times;
     /* border: 3px ridge #FFDA00; */
}

.header
{
     background: #0B0909;
     color:#fff;
     padding: 25px;
     font-family: 'Special Elite', Arial, serif; 
     font-weight: 400;
     text-align: center;
}

.sliderFade 
{ 
    position:relative;
    width:940px; 
    height: 300px;
}

.sliderFade img 
{ 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;
    top:0; 
    border: 5px solid #FFDA00; 
    width:930px; 
    height: 295px;
}

#container1
{
    position:relative; 
    width:940px; 
    height: 200px; 
}

dl, dt, dd, ul, li, a
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #0B0909;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', Arial, serif; 
}

li
{
    padding-left: 2px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-left: 3px solid #FFDA00;
    border-right: 3px solid #FFDA00;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFDA00;
    background-color: white;
    height: 200px; 
}

dl
{
    width: 300px;
    position:relative;
}

dt
{
    padding-top: 4px;
    background-color: #FFDA00;
    border-left: 3px solid #FFDA00;
    border-right: 3px solid #FFDA00;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #CDCDCD;
}

dt a
{
    color: #0B0909;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', Arial, serif; 
}

.footer
{
     background: #0B0909;
     color:#fff;
     padding: 25px;
     font: 0.8em, serif;
     height: 100px;
     border-top: 3px solid #FFDA00;
}
```

**JQuery**

> ```
>           $(function()
>           {
>               //Hide all images except the first in content slider
>               $('.sliderFade :gt(0)').hide();
>
>               setInterval(function()
>               {
>
>                   $('.sliderFade img:first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.sliderFade');
>                   //$('#star').clone().animate({height:"30px"}).appendTo('.outside');
>               }, 4000);
>
>
>               //hide all sub-windows on load
>               $("dd:not(:first)").hide();
>
>               //slide the window up on click
>               $("dt a").click(function()
>               {
>                   $("dd").slideUp("slow");
>                   $(this).parent("dt").next("dd").slideDown("normal");
>               });
>           });
> ```

**HTML**

```
<body>
        <div class="outside">
            <img id= "star" src="star.png" height="10px" width="15px">
        </div>


        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="header" >
                <h1> My web app </h2>
            </div>

            <div class="sliderFade">
                  <img id = "1stImage" src="space2.jpg">
                  <img id = "2ndImage" src="space.jpg">
                  <img id = "3rdImage" src="paint-types.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="clear" />

            <div id="container1">
                <dl>
                    <dt><a href="#">Home</a></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </dd>

                        <dt><a href="#">Blog</a></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </dd>

                        <dt><a href="#">Contact</a></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>


            <div class="footer">
                        <dt><a href="#">Blog</a></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </dd>

                        <dt><a href="#">Contact</a></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </dd>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

thanks.

Comment: @Keith Hi Keith i have just updated the question with the HTML mark-up thanks for the reply. K.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add return false in click event...

```
$(function()
          {
              //Hide all images except the first in content slider
              $('.sliderFade :gt(0)').hide();

              setInterval(function()
              {

                  $('.sliderFade img:first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.sliderFade');
                  //$('#star').clone().animate({height:"30px"}).appendTo('.outside');
              }, 4000);


              //hide all sub-windows on load
              $("dd:not(:first)").hide();

              //slide the window up on click
              $("dt a").click(function()
              {
                  $("dd").slideUp("slow");
                  $(this).parent("dt").next("dd").slideDown("normal");
               return false;
              });
          });
```

hope this will work...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `return false` or `preventDefault()` to stop the anchor links from functioning on click.

Comment: Thank you isherwood this resolved the problem, i added the return false statement at the bottom and it solved the issue.